# Using Git version control software with IAR Embedded Workbench

Tags: embedded, control, software, ide, iar

I have been using Git / Bitbucket to manage versioning for Altium and MPLAB and have recently started using IAR for the STM8 series MCUs for a series of projects. Is there any Git integration to IAR Embedded Workbench or will this be a more manual / external process of versioning? I see that SVN is supported, but am not interested in going back to SVN only for this IDE. Help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess this is the wrong question for this forum, but so far I only found one git Gui which is not totally bad. Try gitkraken. And from my experience, most IDE integrations of a DVCS suck, as they only offer a subset of functionality and lack good visualisation.

So my advice is accept to use a second tool. Do not insist on IDE integration.

Comment: Certainly a good point regarding integrated functionality vs external tool. I am currently using the command line for controlling git functions if what I need is not available in the IDE itself. 

You like gitkraken?

Comment: I started with mercurial in 2008 or so. git from comandline is a nightmare for me. at least compared to mercurial :-) Also I love mecurials tortoisehg gui which is lean, logic and so functional... I think I tried every free git gui to find something similar. Sourcetree [https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/] - the second best so far... gitahead, gitcola,... but only gitkraken is complete enough for my expectations. I realy like it... well at least for a git gui

Comment: Great, thanks for the info! I have no experience with mercurial and came from a company that used SVN exclusively. Now that I am out on my own I opted for Git. gitkraken is downloaded and that's the route I will take with IAR. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with keeping version control out of the programming IDE, I have nothing but bad experience from such. Multiple monitors and separate programs is a much better solution.